# Who solved the particle-in-a-box model first?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential

I got curious who invented the [particle-in-a-box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box) model first. It is really simple and intuitive. I was googling to find the original author who suggested it but I only get textbook or webpages as results.

Comment: It wasn't one of the systems that Schrödinger studied the quantization of in his early papers on wave mechanics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The eigenvalue problem of a free particle constrained by “vessel walls” or an “infinite potential well” is mentioned without details by Schrödinger ([1926](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:52.0966.01), [p. 523](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k153811/f543); [translation](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.211600/page/n48)) and Hund ([1927](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01400234), p. 747). An early reference giving the energy levels and eigenfunctions seems to be Condon and Morse’s book ([1929](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:55.1172.09), [p. 44](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?u=1&id=uc1.$b568098&num=44)).